# Using my desktop multiple monitors on my laptop

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I have a windows setup at home that I use mainly for gaming and other stuff, but for work have been given a separate windows laptop. Basically, instead of switching my monitors over each time from my desktop to my laptop, I would like to be able to just connect to my laptop and use all my desktop monitors, when the laptop itself has just the one. I've seen there are some ways this can be done through vnc, and I am unsure if I could do this natively in windows through the 'connect to wireless display feature'.

Any advice on how I could do this? Thanks

Comment: Both ideas are doable but it's not like you'll be able to use multiple monitors like you have now.

Comment: Does your laptop support Miracast?  And then also the monitor you wish to use?

Comment: The laptop does support miracast, but the monitors are just connected to my desktop pc through hdmi/displayport. I'd simply rather connect from my desktop to my laptop and use the displays like that, if that makes sense. I dont believe they support miracast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the [SPACEDESK Tool](https://www.spacedesk.net/). The main PC will be the server, the laptop screen will become the secondary display.
Maybe other ideas will appear on the combination and connection of your equipment.

Comment: I have tested this out and works pretty well. As far as I can tell it creates a virtual display adapter that is then displayed on my desktop, allowing it to extend, although I was wondering if you knew anyway I could do so multiple times, as currently only one of my desktop displays can be used.

Comment: Edit: Turns out you can literally start the client multiple times, providing additional displays. Seems very smooth even over wifi and three displays :)